# Streaming realtime video with alpha layer

Tags: h.264, opacity, libav

I am working on a project that converts RGBA images to h264 (NAL), streams them to a client browser, decodes the frames and displays them on a canvas using Broadway.js .

My current problem is that when my images contain data in the alpha layer, it is lost in the video stream.

It seems that h264 is not capable of embedding anything alpha layer. I have tried h265 but the encoding times were doubled.

Are there any alternative codecs which are fast enough for realtime streaming but do support an alpha layer? Or a way to have an alpha layer in the h264 stream.

Comment: Google's VP8 may help. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/07/Alpha-transparency-in-Chrome-video